# Ruby Gem Delayed_Job: Does not process jobs stored in lib folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job

I have installed the Ruby gem Delayed_Job to run tasks in a queue, but it shows some behavior that I don't understand. Delayed_Job is using my local active_record so a very standard installation.

I have the code for a job in a file called test_job.rb in my /lib folder

```
    class TestJob
        # Create a entry in the database to track the execution of jobs
        DatabaseJob = Struct.new(:text, :emails) do
            def perform
                # Perform Test Code
            end
        end
    def enqueue
        #enqueue the job
        Delayed::Job.enqueue DatabaseJob.new('lorem ipsum...', 'test email')
    end
end
```

When I try to call the code from a controller like this, the first time the job seems to get submitted (is listed in rake jobs:work) but it does not run:

```
require 'test_job' 
class ExampleController < ApplicationController

      def index
      end

      def job
        # Create a new job instance
        job = TestJob.new
        # Enqueue the job into Delay_Job
        job.enqueue
      end
    end
```

Then when I change the controller code to do what my lib class does, it works perfectly. The job does not only get submitted to the queue, but also runs and completes without failures.

```
require 'test_job'

class ExampleController < ApplicationController
    # Create a entry in the database to track the execution of jobs
        DatabaseJob = Struct.new(:text, :emails) do
            def perform
                # Perform Test Code
            end
        end

  def index
  end

  def job
    #enqueue the job
    Delayed::Job.enqueue DatabaseJob.new('lorem ipsum...', 'test email')
  end
end
```

The strange thing is that when I switch back to calling the lib job class it works without a problem. Then it does not matter whether the struct is directly defined in the controller or in the class in the lib folder.

Defining the struct inside the controller and submitting the job to the queue this way always seems to work, but afterwards also the lib class starts working and sometimes the lib class works even after a restart of the rails server.

Any ideas? Thank you very much for the help.

Best,

Bastian

Comment: You should clean up the whitespace on your code pastes

Comment: Okay, thanks for the note. I have only left the white spaces that make sense e.g. between methods.

Comment: You have included the code for `DatabaseJob` both within the `TestJob` as well as the `ExampleController`. Not sure why you have duplicated the code. May be it has to do with delayed_job executing the wrong code.

Comment: @Dharam That is true I have changed it now, but it does not seem to change the behavior that I have described in my post. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: If you changed your code, could you update your question with the updated code?

Comment: It is updated now.

Comment: If the job is failing to execute, the job should be updated with the exception that caused the failure.